# random or rand function prints the same value, even in different machines

Tags: c, random

I want to print a random number in the range 1 to 6. I have the following code.

```
printf("The random value is %d \n",random(6));
```

It is printing  1804289383 every time I run the code. Even on different machines. I also tried rand(6) still output is same. Even I removed 6, output does not change. Please suggest how to fix it

Thanks in Advance

Sanket

Comment: Are you calling `randomize()` before you call `random()` the first time?

Comment: @Joel, are you referring to srand()?

Comment: @mdec I believe that `randomize()` calls `srand(...)` internally, using the time as the seed. But that may not be ISO compliant. I was commenting based  on past experience.

Comment: @Joel, is there a standard library function called `randomize()`? I had a quick look but apologies if I missed it.

Comment: @Joel, No problem, I was just wondering why I couldn't locate documentation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoud have `srand()` before `rand()` to generate new numbers each time. This code will show how do that:

```
# include <time.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# inlcude <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    printf("The random value is %d\n", 1 + rand() % 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and make sure that you only use srand once in your main function!

Comment: Anyone who might have multiple processes starting at the same time, but wants each to see a different sequence from `rand()`, may need to generate something more likely to be unique... e.g. `srand(time(0) ^ (getpid() << 3) ^ (getpid() >> 2));`.  Better yet, use [the C++11 random number functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `random()` does not take any arguments.

Secondly, from the [fine manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html):

> Like *rand()*, *random()* shall produce by default a sequence of numbers that can be duplicated by calling *srandom()* with 1 as the seed.

So, unless you explicitly specify a seed by calling `srandom()`, `random()` will produce the same sequence of values every time.

Thirdly, `random()` returns a `long` so you should be using `%ld` in your `printf()` call.

Fourthly, learn about your compiler's warning flags, turn them all on, and pay attention to their output. You can turn off some of the warning flags once you understand why it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random integers to be returned by rand().  These sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.
>
> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.

So here's a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RSEED 2

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  srand(RSEED);
  printf("The random value is %d\n", rand());
  return 0;
}
```